# Auto-rotate and cut scanned photos

Tags: photos, photo-editing

I have scanned a lot of family photos, 2 by 2 (and sometimes more), and I need to batch-process them in order to get one file / scanned photograph.
I would need to:

- Separate the 2+ scanned photographs present in the file
- Remove whitespace around each one of them
- Auto-rotate each one of them (because some are slightly tilted)

And I need to process 100's of them.

Is there a software that do this?

I would prefer Linux software if possible.

Comment: The photos have different sizes? Also, are they placed in different positions on each scan?

Comment: @Zuul: yes and yes.

Comment: Humm.. I've been playing around with a solution for this, I'll place an answer with what I've accomplished!